# Stats test for nominal data:

Tags: categorical-data, model-comparison, agreement-statistics

I have to validate if two different methodologies yield statistically similar results to prove if we can use either of the methodologies.

both the methodologies use the same sample, i.e same group of respondents are used for both. At the end of the study both the methdologies will indicate a nominal value for the respondent ( e.g group 1, group 2, ..... , group 6). I need to validate that both the results are similar or not

Method1      Method2

Group1         Group1
Group3         Group2
Group4         Group4
Group1         Group1
.              .
.              .
.Group 6       Group5

At the end I will have close to 250 respondents, since the end result of both methodologies is nominal data , what test can I do to check if they can be used interchangebly

Nirmal

Answer (score 1):

The most popular method for assessing agreement between two unordered categorical variables is Cohen's kappa. He first outlined it in 1960 in an article entitled "A coefficient of agreement for nominal scales" available [here](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/001316446002000104). It computes agreement between the methods and then corrects it for chance agreement. It should be available in most standard statistical software. There are more than 100 threads on this site tagged [cohens-kappa](/questions/tagged/cohens-kappa) and browsing some of them may help you if you want further details.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic set-up  for a McNemar's test (extended to more than two outcomes, which is common in software packages).  But I'm not sure this test will actually tell you what you want.  It will test to see if one response is more "popular" with one method than the other.  The two methods could give different results, but if they change randomly, and not toward one response, McNemar wouldn't pick this up as a significant change.

You should think clearly about what it is that you would like to look at to determine interchangeability.

Maybe you just want to look at the percentage of different results from one test to another, and have some cutoff for this percentage?

You might look at the proportion of Agree / Total_tests, and calculate a confidence interval for this proportion.  Minimally, this proportion should be above chance (0.167). You would like to see this confidence interval approach 1.00.  How close to 1.00 would need the the confidence interval to contain is a judgement call for you to make.